# Xcode 9 no longer copies xcassets into bundle target

Tags: xcode, bundle, xcode9

I updated to Xcode 9 and now when I build my bundle target, it no longer contains the xcasset images resources.

**Setup:**

1. The xcasset is associated with the target
   [image: Xcode 9 showing association with target]
2. The xcasset is included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" of the bundle target's Build Phases.

[image: Xcode 9 showing copy bundle resources]

**Result**

The images within the xcassets are not present with the bundle product.
[image: Terminal showing result of build]

On a different machine with Xcode 8 I can build the same bundle target and the images within the TestCatalog are present.

Note: the TestImage.png (that exists outside of any xcassets) is included as expected on Xcode 9.  This leads me to think that the issue is related to how xcassets are included.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working just fine! *Assets.car* is actually your asset catalog, and your images are inside it.

If Xcode was previously pulling the images out of the asset catalog and putting them at the top level of the framework, that was wrong behavior! Asset catalog images are supposed to be compiled into the compiled version of the asset catalog (the *.car* file). And that is now exactly what is happening. And there is no reason why the asset catalog should not be renamed in the course of compilation (since there is no way you can refer directly to an asset catalog by name in code anyway).

You could confirm that that's what happened by reading the Report generated during compilation. You don't include that in your screen shot, however. I'll show you. Here's my project, similar to yours:

[image]

And here's the relevant part of the report:

[image]

As you can see the last couple of lines, `MyFrameworkAssets.xcassets` has been compiled to the asset catalog called `/MyCoolFramework.framework/Assets.car`, exactly as in your project.

So I think the problem is merely that you are trying to look at this "from the outside" (i.e. using Terminal). The way really to know whether this is working is for your framework code to refer to an image and display it, and it seems you have no such code. You can also download [AssetCatalogTinkerer](http://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer) and look inside the *assets.car* file. You will see that your image is in there!

Comment: You're right, thanks!
FYI: When using the actool with --minimum-deployment-target < 7.0 it creates the Assets.car and ALSO copies all the pngs from within the xcassets to the bundle.  Updating my minimum deployment target to 8.0 was what caused the change and not Xcode 9 itself (although Xcode 9 was why I had to update the minimum deploy target because it doesn't support xibs built for iOS earlier than 7!).

Comment: “ALSO copies all the pngs from within the xcassets to the bundle” Because you’re asking to run on a version of the system so insanely old that asset catalogs hadn’t even been invented yet!

Comment: This post is very accusatory in its wording... it's perfectly reasonable to look in there and see only one file where you expected dozens, and assume that the dozens weren't placed in there (especially if they had been for a long time before). The parenthetical at the end is wholly unnecessary.